# Como estabelecer uma conexão P2P?

Tags: python-3.x, conexão

Em uma conexão normal, é preciso que quem vai receber a conexão esteja com uma porta aberta no roteador (transmitindo para um computador da rede interna). Mas em uma conexão P2P isso não acontece.

Como programas P2P funcionam independente dessa porta aberta? Como por exemplo, programas como *torrent* ou *Gnutella* fazem varias conexões com nós da rede, no caso do *torrent* tem o tracker que pode de alguma forma trabalhar como mediador e criar uma conexão entre as maquinas, mas no caso do *Gnutella* não existe algo centralizando, existe apenas uma lista de nós para se conectar.

Como posso implementar essa conexão inicial? Partindo do pressuposto que não é uma conexão local e que não há nenhuma porta aberta no roteador (como normalmente ocorre) (Não precisa necessariamente do código, só o conceito é suficiente)

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse projeto https://pypi.org/project/pyp2p/

Answer (score -1):

**Primeiro**, Você pode usar qualquer método de Python para criar a comunicação da rede P2P, pode usar `socket` se quiser programar em mais baixo nível, ou pode usar `flask` como servidor e `request` como clientes, ou qualquer biblioteca que permita a criação de um cliente e um servidor, você pode usar `threading` para programar em paralelo e manter varias conexões ao mesmo tempo.

**Segundo**, o *Tracker* do *Torrent* é um servidor intermediário que guarda as informações dos peers, o que facilita para eles encontrarem os outros na internet, quando não existe um servidor desse tipo, é necessário um tipo de método de procura nos próprios peers o que é bem mais difícil de se implementar, mas existem maneiras como *IRC* ou sites na internet que fornecem essas informações.

**Terceiro**, tem um milhão de técnicas para criar uma conexão P2P, pode usar *Port-Forward* para redirecionar os pacotes recebidos pelo IP publico para um IP privado na sua rede, ou pode usar servidores *ICE*(Interactive Connectivity Establishment) que usa *Turn* e *Stun*, entre outras é só pesquisar.